# What is the purpose of fragment recycling by FragmentManager in Android?

Tags: android, fragment, fragmenttransaction, fragmentmanager

I know that `Fragment` should be created and added to the manager using `FragmentTransaction` when the fragment is used for the first time. But later it can be found by `findFragmentById` or `findFragmentbyTag` after configuration changes such as screen rotation.

But on screen rotation, I found that the constructor and all the call back methods of the fragment `onAttach`, `onCreate`, `onCreateView`, `onStart`, `onResume` are called again, even if the fragment is returned from `findFragmentByTag` not explicitely calling the constructor.

The fact that the constructor is called implies that the fragment object can be garbage-collected. Then what part of the fragment is actually stored on configuration changes? If the fragment object is garbage-collected and recreated, then what is the purpose of recyling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fragment is not recycled. If you logged `Fragment.toString()` after screen orientation, you would get a different value meaning those fragment instances are different, created from scratch. All lifecycle methods are called *BUT* you are able to persist some values through `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`.

This is not true for fragments where you called `setRetainInstance(true)`. Now the only lifecycle methods that are repeating are `onCreateView`, `onViewCreated`, (long pause), `onDestroyView`. The instance is the same, the field variables are retained.

**EDIT:**

> Does Android OS automatically destroy and create the fragment and set the same Tag and ID before onCreate is called on the hosting Activity?

TL;DR: Yes.

The [`FragmentState`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/app/Fragment.java#FragmentState) class field variables contain information about one fragment which is *always* retained (among others tag and id).

When you rotate screen [`FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState(...)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/5.0.2_r1/android/app/FragmentManager.java#FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState%28android.os.Parcelable%2Cjava.util.ArrayList%29) is called which either grabs retained fragments or instantiates new fragments and reattaches them to the new activity. This happens as part of `Activity.onCreate(Bundle)`.

> Then what part of the fragment is actually stored on configuration changes?

The `FragmentState` as described above plus anything you or the framework writes in `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)`. If the fragment is marked as retained, everything except view hierarchy is saved.

> If the fragment object is garbage-collected and recreated, then what is the purpose of recyling it?

If it's destroyed and created from scratch (new instance) it's not recycling at all. You either *retain* the fragment instance - the same instance survives screen orientation change - or save and restore instance state - old fragment instance is destroyed, new fragment instance is created and filled with some data from the old instance.

Comment: Then, how can I get the reference to the fragment by calling `findFragmentByTag` in `onCreate` of the hosting Activity? Does Android OS automatically destroy and create the fragment and set the same Tag and ID before `onCreate` is called on the hosting Activity after rotation?

Comment: @jenddy Hi, please check the updated answer. In short: Yes, the activity is able to remember the tags and ids.